# Angular 4 rxjs: Filter data in observable array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an Observable of an array:

```
schools: Observable<SchoolVM[]>;
```

And I need to filter this observable into another for an Autocomplete select

```
filteredSchools: Observable<SchoolVM[]>;
```

I subscribe to the form.valueChanges

```
this.formChange = this.searchForm.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(300)
  .subscribe( value => {
    this.filteredSchools = this.schools.filter(s => s.SchoolName == value);
  });
```

I have an error: Property 'SchoolName' does not exist on type 'SchoolVM[]'
How can I solve it?
And also: I have to filter by 2 different criteria.  It is correct to filter like

```
this.filteredSchools = this.schools.filter(s => s.SchoolName == value || 
    s => s.SchoolName == value);
```

---

I rewrote the function following [Aakash Jain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46423987/3441882), like that:

```
this.formChange = this.searchForm.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(300)
      .subscribe( value => {
        this.filteredSchools = this.schools.map(schools => {
          return schools.filter((school: SchoolVM) => (school.SchoolName === value) || (school.City === value));
          // this.logger.info(this.filteredSchools);
        });
      });
```

and now I get the error "schools.filter" is not a function.

The observable

```
schools: Observable<SchoolVM[]>;
```

is filled from an httpClient call:

```
this.schoolService.filterSchools(arg)
      .subscribe(d => {this.schoolsToFilter = d; })
```

And in the service:

```
filterSchools(arg: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.from(this.http.get('/api/school/find/' + arg));
```

Maybe their is a problem with Observable, but the schools observable is well filled:

{
    "SchoolID": 13028,
    "SchoolName": "100% Conduite",
    "City": "MEUDON",
    "ZipCode": "92190",
    "Street": "17 rue des Gallons",
    "Phone": "01 49 66 06 02"
  },
  {
    "SchoolID": 6803,
    "SchoolName": "100% PERMIS",
    "City": "BADONVILLER",
    "ZipCode": "54540",
    "Street": "25 rue du Maréchal Foch",
    "Phone": ""
  },...

Answer (score 2):

`schools` and `filteredSchools` are Observables that each contain an array of `SchoolVM` objects.

So when you do this:

```
this.schools.subscribe(s => console.log(s));
```

You will find that an array of `SchoolVM` gets printed. So the value of `s` above is not a single `SchoolVM` but instead an `SchoolVM[]`.

As such, when you write:

```
this.filteredSchools = this.schools.filter(s => s.SchoolName == value);
// this will not work since s is an array
```

Instead, what you want to do is:

```
this.filteredSchools = this.schools.map(schools => {
    return schools.filter((school: SchoolVM) => school.SchoolName === value);
});
```

---

To filter by two conditions, your way is incorrect. What you are doing is defining two anonymous functions. This will give you a syntax error. Instead you want one anonymous function with the OR condition.

```
this.filteredSchools = this.schools.map(schools => {
    return schools.filter((school: SchoolVM) => (school.SchoolName === value) || (school.NumberOfStudents >= 100));
});
```

Comment: I rewrote the autoselect code like that:                              
 this.formChange = this.searchForm.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(300)
      .subscribe( value => {
        this.filteredSchools = this.schools.map(schools => {
          return schools.filter((school: SchoolVM) => (school.SchoolName === value) || (school.City === value));
          // this.logger.info(this.filteredSchools);
        });
      }); and now I get the error "schools.filter is not a function".  Any help please?

Comment: @Marcos try `this.formChange = this.searchForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(300).subscribe(val‌​ue => this.schools.subscribe(schools => console.log(schools)))` and let me know what it logs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Aakash.  With your function I have the error ERROR TypeError: _this.schools.subscribe is not a function.  Maybe because schools is Observable<SchoolVM[]>?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add braces. Try this instead: `this.formChange = this.searchForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(300).subscribe(val‌​ue => { this.schools.subscribe(schools => console.log(schools)); })`. Since it is an Observable, subscribe should definitely work. What we need to determine is whether the value emitted by the observable is a `SchoolVM[]` or `null`.

Comment: I have the error  TypeError: _this.schools.subscribe is not a function

Comment: This seems to be a wider problem with how your Observables are defined. I will need to take a look at your full code to address the problem. Please post as much of your component's code as you can reveal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155324/discussion-between-aakash-jain-and-marcos).